# How to Update an old theme for the latest wordpress version

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, updates

Ok, so to start off I'm no Theme developer, but I have a little bit of experience with PHP, and quite a bit of experience (Several Years constant work) with wordpress in general.

I have a current client that wants to use a wordpress theme he saw exampled on another website. I found out that it's the (now outdated) [Ridizain](https://wordpress.org/themes/ridizain/) theme, which hasn't been updated in a few years. I know the theme is a modification of the Twenty Fourteen theme, so I could probably make some CSS Changes to 2014 and come up with the same look.

However, I'm wondering If I could just download the Ridizain theme and make any necessary changes to update it for the latest version of wordpress. I have a test server that I run and it does not seem to have any direct conflicts when I install it.

Is there a resource out there for Theme developers that details what needs to be changed/updated in a theme to bring it in line with each new version of wordpress? If not, where would I begin looking for what needs to be changed/watched out for?

Thanks!

Comment: Look if child theme is created, if it is then you can simply replace parent theme folder to the updated one without loosing style changes.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is *exceptionally* backwards compatible, so it is typical even for older themes to just work for a long time.

However for solid results you would want to perform several meaningful actions:

1. Straight up code review, if your experience and time allows. Just read through all of the code, gauge if it makes sense.
2. Running through everything with `WP_DEBUG` enabled. Straight errors will come up, but also any formally deprecated functions/features will emit warnings with suggestions to update.
3. Run through [Theme Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) plugin and see what comes up. You don't necessarily want to bother with all of that for custom theme, but it's a good to see what's up.
4. If you customize theme for private use — make a proper fork of it, changing name and details. Otherwise you risk invalid update from the repo destroying your changes. However *do* keep proper attribution to original author for copyright/licensing reasons.